# GET Errors in console

Tags: meteor

This error is continuing to occur in my console. I am not refreshing or interacting with the app at all. I am just sitting here, watching. Does anyone know what this error means?

```
GET http://localhost:3000/sockjs/info?cb=poa8l4xy7q   ...   sockjs-0.3.4.js:832
```

Comment: That looks like normal polling behavior of sockjs for non-websocket clients.  Surprised its showing up in console though. What browser are you using?

Comment: When do you get these errors? I get them too on chrome if I have a project open and stop meteor running

Comment: @boingy, I get them while my app is running.

I'm assuming this isn't something I should be worrying too much about.

Answer (score 0):

If this were on a hosted server, I would guess:

- You have websockets turned on for your Meteor app (on by default) but somewhere between Chrome and the webserver there is a component that does not support websockets.  So Chrome periodically tries to upgrade the connection to websockets but it never works.
- There is a load-balancing issue that alternately connects your client to two different Meteor servers.  I would expect this to cause a flash of content though so if you aren't seeing that, its probably not this problem.

Since this is `localhost` and your app is actually still working I don't know why that's happening but perhaps the above guesses will help you track it down.

EDIT: Are you sure your app is still working when you see these?  Can you actually insert/update data and see the changes reflected in the database?